# Cannot connect to localhost during test execution

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, junit, localhost

I'm testing spring-boot application and want to check simple get request. The thing is that if I replace localhost with our dev server everything works fine. 
But not with localhost.

**This is parent test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceStarter.class)
public abstract class AbstractModulIntegrationTest { ... }
```

**The problem:**

```
@Test
    public void testGetRequest() {
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials
                = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass");
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
                .build();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/abc/v1/users/001");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(request);  //HERE IT FAILS
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("RETURN CODE:" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
```

**Stracktrace:**

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your local server listening on port 9000?  Try a web browser or telnet to check.

Comment: Yes. It`s on port 9000

Comment: And a standard program can connect to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@SpringBootTest` does not start a web server by default. You can ask it to start on a defined port or a random port using the `webEnvironment` attribute

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceStarter.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractModulIntegrationTest { ... }
```

You can inject the actual port of the server in your test as follows:

```
@LocalServerPort
private int port;

public void testGetRequest() {  ... }
```

If you want to start on a defined port, you probably have configured your app to start on port 9000 (`server.port=9000`). Then you should do this instead:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceStarter.class, webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractModulIntegrationTest { ... }
```